# Apache PHP with XCache, do I need to optimize Apache modules?

Tags: php, apache

In Centos 6.5 machine, 3 CPU total 9 GHz, 8 GB RAM, Plesk 12.
PHP 5.4.36, Apache/2.2.15, Apache run PHP as PHP module, XCache 3.2.0.

Currently I see 180-200 simultaneous visitors in popular hours. 40-50 simultaneous visitors average.
Current httpd.conf values:

```
Timeout 60
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

xcache.ini values:

```
xcache.size  24M
xcache.count 1
xcache.slots    8K
xcache.var_size 1M
xcache.var_count    1
```

[xcache screenshot 1](http://s23.postimg.org/b1cfnh71n/xcache1.gif)
[xcache screenshot 2](http://s23.postimg.org/n4hrb1i3v/xcache2.gif)

I'm checking what can I do more to optimize Apache. I checked `top` state, it's like this:
[Top results image](http://s28.postimg.org/qhsj1ptcd/top.gif)
Note that each Apache process takes 55-100 mb, where shared memory for each httpd process is 18m.

I'm curious that whether disabling some Apache modules is good or bad.
Because of XCache is it meaningful to disable unused modules ?
Or is it not logical to disable them because in peak times system creates 30-32 httpd processes and it doesn't take too much ?
Currently active apache modules are like this: [screenshot](http://s21.postimg.org/lwmtltkx3/apache.gif)

[httpd process' memory, cpu and count graph](http://s2.postimg.org/pzlixl29l/httpd_process.gif)

Edit:
I restarted httpd process and I see following values:
[top image](http://s2.postimg.org/f542vnj5l/top2.gif)
Note that average httpd process decreased 67 mb to 34 mb.

Answer (score 0):

From the very limited information you've provided there's probably a few things which would make your site go faster, but you [can't use VIRT, RES and SHRD to measure per process memory usage](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/accurate-capacity-planning-with-apache.html).

Removing modules you don't need will have a very small impact on memory usage - but is good practice as it has a big impact on security. Whether or not you are using xcache is irrelevant.

```
 KeepAliveTimeout 15
```

This is just silly.

Since your keepalives are disabled, it's not doing anything. If they were enabled you would have LOTS of httpd processes hanging around on socket connections with no traffic. It should be a *maximum* of 3 (and that assumes you've got a lot of clients on very slow connections). If your site is particularly AJAX heavy then use an event based proxy in front of Apache.

While I applaud the diversity of open-source software, I would question whether running xcache with PHP 5.6 is a good idea.